# Как убить все потоки, если условие выполнено?[PYTHON]

Tags: python, многопоточность, threading

Я создаю 300 поток для парсинга, когда 1 поток выполнит условие , мне нужно что бы все остальные потоки прекращались.

```
def start_requst(productid,item_name,):
while True:
    response = requests.post('https://www.binance.com/bapi/nft/v1/friendly/nft/nft-trade/product-detail',
                             headers={'content-type': 'application/json'}, json={"productId": productid}).json()
    if (response['data']) != None:
        rsp = (response['data']['productDetail'])
        if (rsp['title']) == item_name and float(rsp['amount']) < 18 and rsp['currency'] == 'BUSD' and float(rsp['stepAmount']) == 0:
            print(f'https://www.binance.com/ru/nft/goods/blindBox/detail?productId={productid}&isOpen=false&isProduct=1 ' + str((rsp['amount'])+ " " + str(time.time())))
            succ_resp = str(productid)
            print("Условие выполнено : " + str(productid))
            break
        elif (rsp['title']) == item_name:
            break
        else:
            print(productid)
            break


for productid in reversed(range(first_productid,second_productid)):
my_thread = threading.Thread(target=start_requst, args=(productid,item_name))
my_thread.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать глобальную переменную с значением "True". Замените условие цикла на переменную, когда поток выполнит условие измените значение переменной на "False"

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).